# Unity transparent shadow receiving plane for AR app to receive only shadows and not light reflections

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, shadow, fragment-shader, shaderlab

I'm working on a transparent shadow receiving shader for Augmented Reality app in Unity, that is put into a plane which will receive shadows from point light or spotlight. It works fine, but the plane receives light also as you can see in the image.

[Output Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOp1P.png)

I'm using unity 5.6.3p4. Please tell me what could be the problem in this script or what should I change in this code to receive only shadows and not light reflections on the plane?

The Shader Script is below:

```
Shader "SP/InvisibleShadowCasterForPLight" { 
 Properties { 
     _MainTex("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {} 
 } 

 SubShader {
     Pass {
         Blend One One
         Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardAdd" } 
         CGPROGRAM 
         #pragma vertex vert 
         #pragma fragment frag 
         #include "UnityCG.cginc" 
         #pragma multi_compile_fwdadd_fullshadows 
         #include "AutoLight.cginc" 
         sampler2D _MainTex;
         float4 _MainTex_ST;

         struct v2f { 
             float4 pos : SV_POSITION; 
             LIGHTING_COORDS(0,1) 
             float2 uv : TEXCOORD2;
         }; 

         v2f vert(appdata_base v) { 
             v2f o; 
             o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex); 
             o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX (v.texcoord, _MainTex);
             TRANSFER_VERTEX_TO_FRAGMENT(o); 
             return o; 
         } 

         fixed4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
         { 
             float attenuation = LIGHT_ATTENUATION(i); 
             return tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv) * attenuation; 
         } 
         ENDCG 
     }
 }

 Fallback "VertexLit"
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
LIGHTING_COORDS(0,1)
```

with:

```
UNITY_SHADOW_COORDS(0)
```

Then replace:

```
TRANSFER_VERTEX_TO_FRAGMENT(0)
```

with:

```
TRANSFER_SHADOW(o);
```

Finally, in your fragment function, use this:

```
half shadow = SHADOW_ATTENUATION(i);
return tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv) * shadow;
```

That should do it!
Oh, and you may or may not also want to change blendmode to multiplicative... If the above doesn't work, try changing:

```
Blend One One
```

with:

```
Blend DstColor Zero
```